# How to center a content editor webpart on a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part

I've a content editor webpart with a linked js that display a searchbox.
I'd like center my webpart in the page

Here is the html in my js file

```
<div style="display:table; margin:0 auto;width:100%">
    <div style="float:left">
        <input type="text" id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" class="ms-sbplain" style="width: 368px;" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){launchSearch();return false;}">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #c3c3c3; border-left-width:0 ">
        <img  onClick="launchSearch();return false;" title="Search" class="srch-gosearchimg" onmouseover="this.src='\u002f_layouts\u002fimages\u002fgosearchhover30.png'" onmouseout="this.src='\u002f_layouts\u002fimages\u002fgosearch30.png'" alt="Search" src="/_layouts/images/gosearch30.png"/>
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the contents of your content editor web part in a div and apply styling/attributes to the div to center it on the page.

Comment: i edited my post to show you my html

Comment: You can modify the content.  You have width set to 100% - give it a defined width in order for the margin auto setting to work and center the content inside the web part.  The other method is to override the style for the content editor web part - look at the element inspector in browser tools and you can get the ID and classes being used.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the ID of the Search Web Part and then use the align center code.

```
align="center"
```

[align Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp)

Comment: Where do i put this attribute? i see nothing in html edit source on page

Comment: After you have wrapped the webpart in a div like this:    `<div align="center" style="border:1px solid red">
Searchbox 
</div>`    or you could use javascript to add the align attribute to the searchbox.